# Change specific td value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table where there is a row with td of quantity, price and total
When I provide the quantity and price the total automatically generates...

I have another function which append a blank row to the previous row. But the problem is the previous total is coming here as well.. How can I identify separate rows and change the value according to the specific row?

Here's my code..

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quant, #prc").blur(function(){
        var quants = $("#quant").val();
        var prc = $("#prc").val();
        var tot_field = $("#tot").val();
        var tot  = quants * prc;
        $('#tot').html(tot);
    })
});
```

html

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="quant" class="orderquan" value="0" type="text" />
            </td>

        <td id="mrp">
                <input id="prc" class="orderinput" value="0" type="text" />
            </td>

            <td>
               <span id="tot" class="orderquan"></span>
        </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

By doing this only first row is working perfectly but others don't.. I have to add some index associated with each row but i don't know how to do that...

Comment: A JSFiddle would certainly help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: You need to use classes instead of IDS, because IDs have to be unique. And then use DOM traversal functions to update the fields on the same row.

Comment: what is DOM traversal ? how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your IDs to classes:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="quant orderquan" value="0" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="mrp">
            <input class="prc orderinput" value="0" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td> <span class="tot orderquan"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then use jQuery DOM traversal functions to find the input and output fields in the same row of the table:

```
$(function() {
    $("table").on("blur", ".orderquan, .orderinput", function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var quants = row.find(".quant").val();
        var prc = row.find(".prc").val();
        var tot = quants * prc;
        row.find(".tot").text(tot);
    });
});
```

You also need to use delegation with `.on` to bind the handler to dynamically-created elements.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6x3L/2/)